# Strong Markov property given transition functions

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Suppose we are given family of transition functions satisfying Chapman-Kolmogorov equation, what conditions will ensure that there exists a continuous or cadlag Markov process with given transition functions. And what conditions will ensure the existence of Markov process with Strong Markov property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient for transition functions to satisfy Feller property.Here is the link for discussion about the result - [click here](http://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/07/14/feller-processes/)